# Javascript: Parsing HTML table with Cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I am trying to develop a web scraper using Cheerio to parse an HTML table and output the results in a CSV file, unfortunately the code won't return anything. My code is the following:

```
var request = require("request");
var cheerio = require("cheerio");
var fs = require("fs");

var url = "https://stat.epa.gov.tw/";

request(url, function(err, response, html){
if(!err) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    var allitems = $('table.tableAQI').children().children();
    var items = []
    allitems.each(function(index){
        var result = $('table.tableAQI').children().children().eq(index).find("td").text();
        if(result !="") {
            items.push(result);
        }
    });
    fs.writeFile("output2.csv", JSON.stringify(items, null, 4), function(err){
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log("Data has been written");
        }
    });

    console.log(items);
}
});
```

The website provides 2 tables I tried the same code to parse the other table ('table.aqicolor') and it worked just fine so I am not really sure what is wrong.

I appreciate your support.

Comment: `the code won't return anything` What were you trying to return to what? If you want to return something asynchronous, return a Promise.

Comment: I want to append the td values of the tables to the items array and then save that array in a csv file. When I run the code the array is empty. I tried the same code for the other table on the site and it returns the values so I am guessing it has something to do with the table.

Comment: So the problem is not that nothing is returned, but that the file isn't populated

Comment: Yes, I guess you are right my bad.

Comment: The data isn't in that response, it's [here](https://stat.epa.gov.tw/map.php?a=getcounty&muid=A1)

Comment: Link appears to be dead at this point, so voting to close as missing a [mcve].